# Customizing Text in WordPress's wp-signup.php

Tags: wordpress

I need to change the following default text on the WordPress multisite signup page (`wp-signup.php`):

> "There is no limit to the number of sites you can have, so create to
>   your heart’s content, but write responsibly!"

...since this WordPress install will be limiting the number of sites a user can create.

Is it possible to override the content of this page without hacking the `wp-signup.php` file or dealing with `.htaccess`?

This WordPress install is being hosted by a third party service and it would be best if I could avoid dealing with modifying these files.

Comment: Doesn't look like it. There isn't a filter for this string, it's just hardcoded in, so you'd probably have to edit it inline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Dave Kiss said in his comment above, this string isn't filterable so you can't filter the text. The string isn't marked either so you can't use a translation file.

I suggest you open a WordPress Trac ticket requesting the text be marked or made filterable.

You can open a new ticket here: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/

Comment: I was afraid of this, but, yeah, it seems that hacking wp-signup.php or doing some redirect of some sort seems to be the only way to do this.

I went ahead and filed a ticket with wordpress. Oh well... Ha! ...and it looks like a ticket I filed 2 years ago on a separate issue is finally on track for 3.7...

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to hit on another solution. It turns out, that since the text on the wp-signup.php page is run through __(), you can alter it using the '[gettext](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/gettext)' filter like so:

```
/**
 * Modify default wp-signup.php text
 */
function themename_wp_signup_text( $translated_text, $untranslated_text, $domain ) {
    global $pagenow;

    if ( is_multisite() && $pagenow === 'wp-signup.php' ) {

    switch ( $untranslated_text ) {
            case 'Welcome back, %s. By filling out the form below, you can <strong>add another site to your account</strong>. There is no limit to the number of sites you can have, so create to your heart&#8217;s content, but write responsibly!' :
            $translated_text = __( 'Welcome back, %s. By filling out the form below, you can <strong>add another site to your account</strong>. You can create a maximum of 5 sites. Remember to write responsibly or some junk! Ciao!', 'theme_text_domain' );
            break;
        }
    }

    return $translated_text;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'themename_wp_signup_text', 20, 3 );
```

...which is just for a theme, but you could do this in a plugin too.

So the text is *technically* filterable, but I'd say this is a huge hack though, but it'll do, and shouldn't have any consequences until that particular text changes in WordPress core...